# Setting label with property observer in UITableViewCell, what's happening

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell, didset

In my custom `UITableViewCell` when the property is set, if there is no label it will create a label and set the text etc. If the label already exists, it shouldn't do anything. The strange thing is, when I tap the cell for the first time it creates the label as it should be. But when I tap the cell again, the label disappears. I've recreated this in a clean project and same thing is happening. What's the cause of this odd behavior?

CustomTableViewCell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var numberLabel: UILabel!
    var views = [String: UILabel]()

    var number: Int = 5 {
        didSet {
            println("AMOUNT: Accessed")
            if numberLabel == nil {
                println("AMOUNT: Amount is nil")

                // Create amount label
                numberLabel = UILabel()
                if number > 0 { numberLabel.text = String(number) }
                numberLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                contentView.addSubview(numberLabel)
                views["amount"] = numberLabel

                // Amount label constraints
                contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: numberLabel, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
                contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[amount(40)]-8-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
            } else {
                println("AMOUNT: Nothing should be changing or happening \n")
            }
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items = [Int]()
    var amount = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 1 }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

        cell.number = amount

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        amount++
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

EDIT:
In response to the comment, my console displays:

```
NUMBER: Accessed
NUMBER: Number is nil
NUMBER: Accessed
NUMBER: Number is nil                                 << label shows "1"
NUMBER: Accessed
NUMBER: Nothing should be changing or happening       << label disappears.

NUMBER: Accessed
NUMBER: Nothing should be changing or happening       << label shows "1" again

NUMBER: Accessed
NUMBER: Nothing should be changing or happening       << label disappears.

NUMBER: Accessed
NUMBER: Nothing should be changing or happening       << label shows "1" again

NUMBER: Accessed
NUMBER: Nothing should be changing or happening       << label disappears.
```

I also changed the background to a color and it just disappears. I suppose it has something to do with the `oldValue` of didSet. The same is happening with `willSet` when I change the values to `newValue`. Nothing happens when I use the "old values" though.

Comment: What's your console output? Is the background color of the label distinct from the background of the cell so would see if its still there just empty?

Comment: added an edit to show you the output

Comment: So the flow is that you click on the cell, in didSelect you reload it, and then set its value? right?

Comment: correct. this value will be evaluated by TableViewCell's property behavior. In this example it should be always false after the first time and should do nothing. But in the simulator, the label appears and disappears (as displayed in my "edit").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is down to the repeated reuse of the same two cells:

Your table only has one row, but you end up creating two cells from scratch which is clear from the initial output. It probably creates two because you reload while using the first cell, forcing a second to be created.

The first cell (A)  will have the number 0 and a blank label.
The second cell (B) will have the number 1 and a label with 1 in it.

When you do the next select, the table reuses cell A which has blank text. Regardless of the number this will always be blank as you never reset the number for a cell which has a label already.

When you do the next select, the table reuses cell B which has text with a 1.

This pattern then repeats because you are always using one cell while calling reload which reuses the other. Hence A,B,A,B.....

To fix the problem, you need to set the label content every time you set the number.

Comment: This might explain why initially, the output shows the label is nil twice.

Comment: And my solution fixes this without even having to understand this underlying reason.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than troubleshooting your setup, let me point out something else: by relying on the label "being there" you are in effect using a UI element as a data source. This is a violation of the MVC (model view controller) pattern and can lead to all sorts of trouble, including your case.

I love the mechanism of having a table view cell have a strong property that I can just set so elegantly as you do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It produces succinct and beautiful code. It separates the data logic from the display, which is coded in the *view* where it belongs.

So for the cell subclass, let me suggest to not create and destroy UI elements as this is not very efficient. Instead, set up all the UI elements you need in storyboard and wire them up in Interface Builder. In the setter of the property, check the value of the `number` property and change the UI elements as needed. If you want to hide the label, set its `hidden` property to `true`.

Ideally, your table view controller should know the state of the cell at the index path. The cell should just do the job of properly displaying this state.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to keep the MVC pattern in mind. I tried keeping the code in my controllers as low as possible, resulting in doing too much in the other classes. Still I really wonder why `didSet` and `willSet` has this behavior.